# Apache Solr - Unable to access admin page

Tags: solr

On mac snow leopard, I have installed Apache Solr 4.2.0 using brew and triggered the server using the below commands,

```
Usage: $ solr path/to/config/dir
```

When I try to access the admin page in browser using below link and the page with SolrCore Initialization failure occurs as below,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin

collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml
```

The page also has message,

```
There are no SolrCores running.
Using the Solr Admin UI currently requires at least one SolrCore.
```

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the root for the Solr config directory, there is a file called `solr.xml`. This file configures Solr cores. The file might contain:

```
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}" hostContext="${hostContext:}" zkClientTimeout="${zkClientTimeout:15000}">
    <core default="true" name="auction" instanceDir="auctionConfigDir" />
  </cores>
```

The important point is to match `instanceDir="auctionConfigDir"` with the actual `path/to/config/dir`. If Solr can't find the location of you configuration files, it wont be able to start a core.

Comment: I don't think it is the path to the config directory. It is the path to the directory containing that config directory.

Answer (score 0):

sudo vim /opt/solr-4.8.1/example/etc/jetty.xml
change

```
<!-- This connector is currently being used for Solr because it
      showed better performance than nio.SelectChannelConnector
      for typical Solr requests.  -->
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
        <Set name="host">127.0.0.1</Set>
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

to

```
<!-- This connector is currently being used for Solr because it
      showed better performance than nio.SelectChannelConnector
      for typical Solr requests.  -->
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
        <Set name="host">0.0.0.0</Set>
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

then
     sudo service solrd restart